# A way to create matched pairs of generic classes without warnings?

Tags: java, generics

I wonder if there is a way to eliminate the rawtypes warning when I use generic classes that refer to each other:

```
public class DummyDeleteMe {
abstract class RightSide<L extends LeftSide>{ //Can I use a type parameter here?
    L getLeftSide() {return _mate;}
    void setLeftSide(L mate) {_mate = mate;}
    L _mate;
    void connectToMate(){
        getLeftSide().setRightSide(this);//warning: 
        /** [unchecked] unchecked call to setRightSide(R) as a member of the raw type DummyDeleteMe.LeftSide
         where R is a type-variable:  * **/
    }
}

abstract class LeftSide<R extends RightSide>{// And here?
    R getRightSide(){return _mate;}
    void setRightSide(R mate) {_mate = mate;}
    R _mate;
}
 class RightSideSub extends RightSide<LeftSideSub>{
    void connectToMate(){
        getLeftSide().setRightSide(this);//No warning
    }
 }
  class LeftSideSub extends LeftSide<RightSideSub>{}
}
```

The compiler warning is because the `LeftSide` in the parameter bound is a raw type. Replacing it with `LeftSide<?>` causes an error in `connectToMate`. Overriding `connectToMate` in `RightSideSub`, the same code does not generate a warning.

I guess I'm looking for some kind of second type parameter, that is self referential:

```
abstract class RightSide<R extends RightSide<R,L>, L extends LeftSide<L,R>>{}
```

But that causes other type mis-match errors in the `R` variables and methods that return `R`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it may solve your problem. Based only on what you've shown in your code sample, there is no need for a generic at all. It's over complicating the issue. That is, if your example is a fairly close match for what you need.

Assuming it is, how about something like this.

```
public interface Half{
    public Half getOtherHalf();
}

public class RightSide implements Half{
    private LeftSide leftSide;

    public void setLeftSide(LeftSide leftSide){
        this.leftSide = leftSide;
    }

    @Override
    public LeftSide getOtherHalf() {
        return leftSide;
    }
}

public class LeftSide implements Half{
    private RightSide rightSide;

    public void setRightSide(RightSide rightSide){
        this.rightSide = rightSide;
    }

    @Override
    public RightSide getOtherHalf(){
        return rightSide;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. I have removed references to `L` for "left side" and `R` for "right side" and replaced them with `T` for "this side" and `O` for "other side"

```
public class Solution1 {
    abstract static class Side<T extends Side<T, O>, O extends Side<O, T>> {
        Side<O, T> _mate = null;

        Side<O, T> getOtherSide() {
            return _mate;
        }

        void setOtherSide(Side<O, T> mate) {
            _mate = mate;
        }

        void connectToMate() {
            getOtherSide().setOtherSide(this);
        }
    }

    //You concrete implementations can replace This and Other
    //with Right and Left as you see fit.

    static class RightSideSub extends Side<RightSideSub, LeftSideSub> {
    }

    static class LeftSideSub extends Side<LeftSideSub, RightSideSub> {
    }
}
```

However, I would suggest another, simpler solution at the cost of loosing `connectToMate()` method and replacing it with code in `main()` method below:

```
class OtherSolution{
    abstract static class Side<O>{
        O _mate = null;
        void setOtherSide(O mate){
            _mate = mate;
        }
    }

    static class RightSideSub extends Side<LeftSideSub> {
    }

    static class LeftSideSub extends Side<RightSideSub> {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RightSideSub rs = new RightSideSub();
        LeftSideSub ls = new LeftSideSub();
        //do the connectToMate() operation externally like this:
        rs.setOtherSide(ls);
        ls.setOtherSide(rs);
    }
}
```